# Laravel navigating to multiple pages within one controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am kind of new to laravel. I'm trying to create a newswebsite. I have an article controller with loops in articles into a view(category view). does someone have a solution to adding multiple 'index' functions so i can use the crud functionality through the same controller for multiple views?

i need this so i dont have to create 8 different controllers for 8 diffrent categories.

i hope the question is clear, if you need more information to solve my problem. feel free to leave a comment

[this is the piece of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H7dV.png)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Setup a route for each category and then let that route point to the correct function in your controller? `Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');` https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing

Comment: Please copy and paste your code in a code block, rather than a screenshot of it.

Comment: i know sorry, but somehow it messed up and i thought it was a fast alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
# /routes/web.php
Route::get('articles/', 'ArticleController@index');
Route::get('articles/{category}/', 'ArticleController@categoryIndex');

# app/http/controllers/ArticleController.php
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::all();
    return view('articles.index')->with(compact('articles'));
}

public function categoryIndex(Category $category)
{
    $articles = Article::where('category_id',$category->id)->get();
    return view('articles.index')->with(compact('articles'));
}
```